# WCF - MSMQ endpoint not found in new environment

Tags: wcf, msmq, netmsmqbinding

### The setup

I have a WCF service hosted in IIS/AppFabric running on Windows Server 2012R2.
The service is bound to a local transactional MSMQ queue via netMsmqBinding. My operations are decorated with TransactionScopeRequired = true.
The service operations recieves calls from a BizTalk server, handles them and send responses back to a remote queue (on the same BizTalk Server), also via a netMsmqBinding.

> ```
> <endpoint name="Outbound" address="net.msmq://int01test.mydomain.com/private/queue.name" binding="netMsmqBinding"  bindingConfiguration="QueueBindingConfigurationOutbound" contract="My.Outbound.Contract" /> 
>
>
>
> <netMsmqBinding>
> <binding name="QueueBindingConfigurationOutbound">
> <security>
> <transport msmqAuthenticationMode="WindowsDomain" msmqProtectionLevel="Sign" />
> </security>
> </binding> 
> </netMsmqBinding>
> ```

In the testing environment this works as intended.

Physical setup in testing environment:
Server int01test.mydomain.com hosts a BizTalk server and my inbound queue.  This runs under service account mydomain\inttestuser.
Server app01test.mydomain.com hosts my application (IIS/AppFabric), my database (SQL server) and my outbound queue. This runs under service account mydomain\apptestuser.

### The problem

When this solution is promoted to the acceptance testing environment, calls are still handled, but the responses are blocked with error message:

> System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: An error occurred while
>   opening the queue:Unrecognized error -1072824317 (0xc00e0003). The 
>   message cannot be sent or received from the queue. Ensure that MSMQ is
>   installed and running. Also ensure that the queue is available to open
>   with the required access mode and authorization. --->
>   System.ServiceModel.MsmqException: An error occurred while opening the
>   queue:Unrecognized error -1072824317 (0xc00e0003). The  message cannot
>   be sent or received from the queue. Ensure that MSMQ is installed and
>   running. Also ensure that the queue is available to open with the
>   required access mode and authorization.

### Differences

In the testing environment, my service and my database is running on a single server instance. (The BizTalk Server and it's queue, the target of my outbound messages, is on another server though)
In the acceptance testing environment, my solution is deployed on two load balanced servers and the database is on a separate cluster.
There are also more strict external firewall rules to mimic the production environment.
Even the BizTalk server is clustered, though we communicate machine-to-machine rather than cluster-to-cluster right now.

So setup in QA Environment is:
Server int01qa.mydomain.com (clustered with int02qa.mydomain.com) hosts a BizTalk server and my inbound queue. This runs under service account mydomain\intqauser.
Server app01qa.mydomain.com (clustered with app02qa.mydomain.com) hosts my application (IIS/AppFabric) and my outbound queue. This runs under service account mydomain\appqauser.
Server db01qa.mydomain.com hosts my database.

### What we've already tried

- We have disabled authentication on the remote queue.
- We have granted full control to the account which my service is running under as well as to "everyone".
- We have, successfully, sent msmq messages manually between the two servers.
- I have configured my service to send responses to a local private queue, same error.

Comment: To eliminate permissions problems, you need to add "Anonymous logon" as well as Everyone. (The latter doesn't include the former).

Comment: Can you please provide names (bogus, if necessary) for the various resources to make it easier to discuss where various resources and services are physically located?

Comment: @JohnBreakwell I added bogus server account names.
Will try to add Aynomous logon as well. (Can't believe I haven't thought of that myself) though the call should not be anonymous really. (msmqAuthenticationMode="WindowsDomain" msmqProtectionLevel="Sign")

Comment: Anonymous access was already granted. That did not help.

Comment: The anon bit was just for completeness. Regarding the extra information, you've provided the server names but not the clustered resources. If you've clustered MSMQ then it shouldn't be running on int01qa - it will be running as a clustered resource. MSMQ can be ~installed~ on int01qa but just don't start the service. My assumption is that the queues aren't where you think they are. (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johnbreakwell/2008/02/18/clustering-msmq-applications-rule-1/)

Comment: Thanks, that is useful info. 
What is confusing me, however, is that
a) changing the endpoint to <endpoint name="Outbound" address="net.msmq://localhost/private/queue.name" binding="netMsmqBinding"  bindingConfiguration="QueueBindingConfigurationOutbound" contract="My.Outbound.Contract" /> 
makes no difference.

b) The queue on int01qa is indeed running and active. I've verified that by running a small powershell script on app01qa that writes to a queue on int01qa.

Is this behaviour consistent with the clustering issues You are describing?

Comment: @JohnBreakwell Thanks for all the help. Even though the problem wasn't in clustering after all you helped me rule out a couple of false leads.

Comment: Actually, my mistake. I thought you had a failover cluster rather than a load-balancing one so my questions weren't really relevant - even though they helped :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem turned out to be that MSMQ couldn't find a certificate for the app pool user. That is, the 
0xc00e0003, MQ_ERROR_QUEUE_NOT_FOUND
was really caused by a 
0xC00E002F, MQ_ERROR_NO_INTERNAL_USER_CERT
Changing security settings to

```
<transport msmqAuthenticationMode="None" msmqProtectionLevel="None" />
```

enabled messages to be sent.
The real solution, of course, is not to disable security but to ensure that the app pool users cerificate is installed in msmq.

Comment: Some tips here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johnbreakwell/2009/01/23/how-to-send-authenticated-msmq-messages-without-using-a-domain-account/

Comment: Interesting read, though I do run my service under a domain account.

Answer (score 0):

We came across this issue and didn't want to disable authentication. We tried a number of different approaches, but it was something to do with the User Certificate not existing we think.

We went to the App Pool of the client application (which calls the WCF endpoint via MSMQ) and changed the `Load Profile` property to `True`. The call then worked. As an aside, changing it back to `false` continued to work - presumably because it had already sorted the certificate issue out.